# Extend Abstract Class with Generic Types?

Tags: java, gwt, extends, gwt-platform

How can I extent an abstract class like the following which has generic arguments?

```
@Singleton
public abstract class Presenter<V extends View, Proxy_ extends Proxy<?>> extends PresenterWidget<V> {

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class `Presenter` has simplified generic type `Presenter<V, Proxy_>` where

- `V` extends `View`
- `Proxy_` extends `Proxy<?>`

Extending class should look like this:

```
public class MyPresenter extends Presenter<MyView, MyProxy> {
    ...
}
```

where

- `MyView` extends `View`
- `MyProxy` extends `Proxy<?>`

Answer (score 0):

To extend MariuszS's answer: Generally the presenter defines the view interface:

```
public class MyPresenter extends Presenter<MyPresenter.MyView, MyProxy> {
    public static interface MyView extends View {
    ...
    }
...
```